# How to get job start time inside of a TSQL agent job step?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

Is there a good way to query the job start time inside of a given sql agent job step (TSQL)?  This will help with step 3 in the following scenario.

**Job Foo** (Run Daily @ 11:30pm)
Step1 - StartTime = Saturday 11:30pm TSQL - (15 minute duration)
Step2 - StartTime = Saturday 11:45pm TSQL - (30 minute duration)
Step3 - StartTime = Sunday   12:15am TSQL - Exit early / don't run unless Foo job was started on a Saturday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script to build a view that shows current job's run status and current step.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE OR ALTER   PROCEDURE ETLSteps.ListJobsCurrentRunningStatus 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
    DECLARE @currentjobstatus TABLE([Job ID] binary(16), [Last Run Date] int, [Last Run Time] int, [Next Run Date] int, [Next Run Time] int, [Next Run Schedule ID] int, [Requested To Run] int, [Request Source] int, [Request Source ID] nvarchar(66), [Running] int, [Current Step] int, [Current Retry Attempt] int, [State] int )
    INSERT INTO @currentjobstatus
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, ''
    SELECT job_id_bin = [Job ID], job_is_running = Running, current_step_id = [Current Step], current_step_retry_attempt_no = [Current Retry Attempt], current_run_status = State FROM @currentjobstatus
    RETURN 0
    DECLARE @rtn int
    EXEC @rtn =  ETLSteps.ListJobsCurrentRunningStatus 
END
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'.\instance', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'.\instance',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=NULL
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'.\instance', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ETLSteps.AgentJobsCurrentlyRunning AS
SELECT 
    job_id = CAST(job_id_bin AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
,   job_id_bin
,   job_is_running 
,   current_step_id 
,   current_step_retry_attempt_no
,   current_run_status 
FROM OPENQUERY([.\instance], 'DBABnch_Local.ETLSteps.ListJobsCurrentRunningStatus') query
GO
SELECT * FROM ETLSteps.AgentJobsCurrentlyRunning
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information about the jobs and SQL Server Agent in `msdb`.

You can check it out below, I added a few columns that help you in your thoughts. Maybe you want to check If this job success or not (in the message column).

```
SELECT  JobName = sj.name,
        StepName = jh.step_name,
        RunDateTime = msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time),
        EndDateTime = DATEADD(SECOND, run_duration / 10000 * 3600 + run_duration % 10000 / 100 * 60 + run_duration % 100, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(jh.run_date, jh.run_time)),
        jh.message
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON sj.job_id = jh.job_id
where step_id=0
```

**For the comment**: There is no clearly answered yet about that. So, you should try it.

Microsoft says;

> In most cases the data is updated only after the job step completes
> and the table typically contains no records for job steps that are
> currently in progress, but in some cases underlying processes do
> provide information about in progress job steps.

Comment: Will the sysjobhistory be populated for the current job even though the job is currently running and hasn't finished?

Comment: I updated my answer, you may check it out.

Comment: It does not appear that msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory is updated while a job is still running, I just checked with a long running job on our production system, and the latest record in sysjobhistory is from yesterday.

You may have better luck with run_requested_date FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity.